# ReactJS - Listing all keys at once

Tags: reactjs

I'm a beginner of ReactJS and I'm stuck trying to figure out why map only returns a single prop at a time.

In file1.jsx, I have an array that contains 3 objects:

```
var MainPanelOneData = [{"id":1,"shotviews":15080},{"id":2,"likes":12000},{"id":3,"comments":5100}];
```

File1.jsx also has a render function to extrapolate the data inside the array:

```
render: function() {
    var ListMainPanelOne = MainPanelOneData.map(function(data) {
        return <MainPanelOne key={data.key} shotviews={data.shotviews} likes={data.likes} comments={data.comments} />
});
```

In file2.jsx, I have this code to render the data object from file1.jsx:

```
render: function() {

    return (
      <div>
      <span>{this.props.shotviews} shot views</span>
      <span>{this.props.likes} likes</span>
      <span>{this.props.comments} comments</span>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

The result shows this:

```
15080 shot views likes comments
shot views12000 likes comments
shot views likes5100 comments
```

I'm guessing it repeats like this because it searches through one key at a time?  If that's the case, how do I display all keys at the same time?  Use indexing?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to show all data keys in a single component? i.e. `shotViews`, `likes`, `comments`?

Answer (score 0):

well your array of data doesnt have all the keys. each one of your objects in `PanelOneData` has ONE key and is missing the other two; additionally none of them have key called `key`. so youre making three `MainPanelOne` components, each with a single prop. the result of that map is this

```
[
  <MainPanelOne key={null} shotviews={15080} likes={null} comments={null} />,
  <MainPanelOne key={null} shotviews={null} likes={12000} comments={null} />,
  <MainPanelOne key={null} shotviews={null} likes={null} comments={5100} />
]
```

which is an accurate display of what youre seeing

Comment: Hmm, I must be misunderstanding what a key is then.  Do you mean that `MainPanelOneData = [{"id":1,"shotviews":15080},{"id":2,"likes":12000},{"id":3,"comments":5100}];` the key for it is MainPanelOneData[0]?  So if I wanted to access shotviews, it would be something like this? MainPanelOneData[0][0].shotviews?  Sorry for my bad syntax, I'm also learning JS after coming from Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

To get one line you might do something like this.

```js
render: function() {
    var ListMainPanelOne = MainPanelOneData.map(function(data) {
        return <span key={data.id}> {data.shotviews} {data.likes} {data.comments} </span>
});
```